# Difference between self.request and request in Django class-based view

Tags: python, django, django-views

In django, for class-based view like `ListView` and `DetailView`, methods like `get()` or `post()` or other functions defined by developer take parameters include `self` and `request`. I learnt that in `self` these is actually a `self.request` field, so wha's the difference between `self.request` and `request`?

Example, this is the function in a class based view and used to handle user's login requirement:

```
def login(self, request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    pwd = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=name, password=pwd)

    if user is not None:
        request.session.set_expiry(0)
        login(request, user)
        log_message = 'Login successfully.'
    else:
        log_message = 'Fail to login.'

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:testindex'))
```

This is the function used to handle user's register:

```
def register(self, request):
    user_name = self.request.POST['username']
    firstname = self.request.POST['firstname']
    lastname = self.request.POST['lastname']
    pwd = self.request.POST['password']
    e_mail = self.request.POST['email']
    user = User.objects.create(username=user_name, first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, email=e_mail)
    user.set_password(pwd)
    try:
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pwd)
        login(self.request, user)
    except Exception:
        pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:testindex'))
```

In the first function, it used data stored in `request` and in the second one, it used `self.request`, both work functionally. What's the difference?

Answer (score 13):

For a subclass of `View`, they're the same object. `self.request = request` [is set in](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/base.py#L89) `view` function that `as_view()` returns. I looked into the history, but only found setting `self.request` and then immediately passing request into the view function.

Comment: This is correct, and same goes with `self.args` and `self.kwargs`. It would be interesting to know why Django was designed with these variables passed as both attributes and function parameters, and if there's a convention or use case for one vs the other.

Comment: Are they the same for mixins as well?

Comment: @SMX have you maybe found out & willing to share? : D